# basic geometry angle problem

Tags: geometry

Two straight lines, AB and AD, lie in the same vertical plane. AB makes an angle of 25 degrees with the horizontal, and AD makes 32 degrees with the vertical. What is the angle between AB and AD?

The answer is 33 degrees or 93 degrees.

I cannot visualize what this question is asking. It says both AD and AD lie on the same vertical plane, then immediately says AD makes 32 degrees with the vertical. Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: Are you sure the answer isn't "$33^\circ$ or $97^\circ$"?

Comment: Don't you want to respond to my comment or my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a three-dimensional coordinate system with the $x$- and $y$-axes on "the ground" and the $z$-axis "vertical."  Imagine further that $AB$ and $AD$ are both lying on, say, the $yz$-plane, that is, the plane with $x=0$.  Thus, they are both on the same vertical plane.

For example, $A$ is at $(0,0,0)$, $B$ is at $(0,\cos(25^\circ),\sin(25^\circ))$, and $D$ is either at $(0,\cos(58^\circ),\sin(58^\circ))$ or at $(0,\cos(122^\circ),\sin(122^\circ))$.